# IDE for web development that recognizes all syntax

Tags: windows, web-development, ide

I am trying to develop an e-commerce website. I am looking for a good IDE which has good code completion (like IntelliSense). I have tried Sublime 2, PhpStorm, NetBeans, Edge Code, Brackets, Notepad++, Dreamweaver, Aptana, jEdit, but nothing seems to be perfect.

It is frustrating when the IDE doesn't recognize certain syntax. For example, `box-sizing` for CSS is not recognized in Sublime 2. Lots of similar issues with both CSS and jQuery syntax. Unlike a programming language like Java where it complies and no syntax error manages to go undetected, having issues with web development.

Is there any IDE out there which is perfect and recognizes every syntax and has good code completion for HTML5, CSS3 and jQuery, Ajax, PHP and jQuery mobile?

Comment: Perfect isn't possible. EVER. Especially in a world of continuously evolving standards. You might want to focus on something which allows updating of the syntax handling, as well as a dev team that tries to keep up.

Comment: So is there any IDE out there which will recognize 'box-sizing' for example.

Comment: Any OS restrictions? Price? License?

Comment: Can you list all the IDEs you've tried?

Comment: @unor no price license restrictions. Looking for Windows compatible.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt phpstorm, edge code, brackets, sublime 2, netbeans, notepad++, dreamweaver, Aptana jEdit

Comment: Visual Studio Express For Web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to be in the same situation until I found [PhpStorm by JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/).

It recognizes all the languages you mentioned (except possibly jQuery Mobile, I'm not sure about that one, but I believe you can configure it to do so), can provide code complete for all of them, syntax highlighting, as well as a ton of other features. The feature set is quite extensive but you can [check it out on their site](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/features/).

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is not **perfect** but given that standards (and hence keywords, syntax etc.) continue to evolve nothing can be perfect for very long unless it has a very fast release cycle. However [SublimeText 3](http://sublimetext.com/) out of the box is pretty good. Yes it has some things that could be better... which is where plugins come in. I could wax poetic about the greatness of Sublime for a long time but then boredom would hit... so I'll keep it short.
I really like [SublimeText](http://sublimetext.com/) as a great text editor (the *best* that I've used in my opinion though I'm sure that could devolve into an opinion argument quite easily). It is not free-ware unfortunately but it does have a full functionality trial so you can decide with proper usage whether it is worth the outlay to you. My favourite aspect has got to be the workspace/project thing of switching between projects and not having to save the files if I'm not ready to. For an improves web development workflow, the plugins I'd reccomend are:

- [SublimeLinter](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeLinter): Linting framework; you'll probably want the language specific lint plugins for whatever you are doing; I suggest: (+++)

  - [SublimeLinter-jshint](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeLinter-jshint): For JavaScript; runs the well known jshint. (+++)
  - [SublimeLinter-contrib-jslint](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeLinter-contrib-jslint): For JavaScript; runs the well known jslint. (+++)
  - [SublimeLinter-json](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeLinter-json): For JSON files. (+++)
  - [SublimeLinter-phplint](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeLinter-phplint): For PHP (++)
  - [SublimeLinter-html-tidy](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeLinter-html-tidy): Runs TIDY for html files - I haven't used this though. (YMMV)
  - [CSSLint](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/CSSLint): Haven't used it yet but will lint your CSS. (YMMV)
- [CSSComb JS](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/CSScomb%20JS): Makes your CSS Stylesheets beautiful and standardized order. (++)
- [Sublice-CSS3](https://github.com/i-akhmadullin/Sublime-CSS3): Gives full CSS3 support - **and that includes `box-sizing`** (+++)
- [CSS Extended Completions](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/CSS%20Extended%20Completions): Supports LESS as well as CSS. This is a supreme auto-complete option; you'll probably want it. (+++)
- [jQuery](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/jQuery): A plugin to help with jQuery development, haven't used it much but so far I like it. (+)
- [Less2Css](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Less2Css): builds the less files to CSS right from SublimeText. (Has a few options including doing it automatically on save) (+)
- [LESS](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/LESS): Syntax Highlighting and some autocompletion. (++)

Answer (score 0):

As others have already said, no IDE will be perfect, but in my experience [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/) is very good for web stuff.  Like NetBeans, it's predominantly a Java IDE but it's very good with HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

The community edition is free so I'd recommend you give it a try.

You may also want to consider JetBrains' specialised web-based IDE, Webstorm: http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm

Comment: What about PHP, AJAX and jQuery? (I would *assume* good PHP support but better to specify)

Comment: I'm not sure about PHP, to be honest, Nick.  I'm sure if it's good for JavaScript it'll be good for AJAX and jQuery.

Comment: Yeah I'd agree it'll be good for recognizing syntax but what about code completion?